# CRC-16/KERMIT Implementation

Tags: php, crc16

I am using the following function to calculate CRC.

```
function crc16_kermit($string) { 

       $crc = 0; 
       for ( $x=0; $x<strlen( $string ); $x++ ) { 

          $crc = $crc ^ ord( $string[$x] ); 
          for ($y = 0; $y < 8; $y++) { 

             if ( ($crc & 0x0001) == 0x0001 ) $crc = ( ($crc >> 1 ) ^ 0x8408 ); 
             else                             $crc =    $crc >> 1; 
          } 
       } 

       $lb  = ($crc & 0xff00) >> 8; 
       $hb  = ($crc & 0x00ff) << 8; 
       $crc = $hb | $lb; 

       return $crc; 
    }
```

But its not showing the result as expected. ie; From this function I got CRC as '2DE3' for the hex value '6c20536574696f20322c31'. But I need to get it as  'EB3E'. I checked the value in 'https://crccalc.com/' .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. Your test is wrong. You did not convert the `6c20...` to binary. `2de3` is the CRC of that ASCII string of digits and letters. If you convert it to binary, then you get `eb3e`.

Though note that, for some reason, the last three lines of your routine reverses the bytes. So you will get `3eeb`.